Error in display the desired output on the webpage with c++ uisng CGI
I am making a music player that has the link stored in a stack.
Error:
I am trying to add the song html to a stack on the webpage it is showing me the following thing when i click on add button or any other
Below is my directory snippet:
enter image description here
the code for index.html is :
`<!-- music-player/html/index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Music Player</title>
    <style>
        body { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }
        .container { max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 20px; }
        .playlist { margin-top: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Music Player</h1>
        <form id="pushForm">
            <input type="text" id="songLink" placeholder="Enter song link" required>
            <button type="button" onclick="addSong()">Add Song</button>
        </form>
        <button onclick="deleteSong()">Delete Last Song</button>
        <button onclick="displayPlaylist()">Display Playlist</button>
        <button onclick="openTopSong()">Open Last Song</button>
        <div class="playlist" id="playlist"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        const apiUrl = '/cgi-bin/music_player.cgi';

        async function addSong() {
            const link = document.getElementById('songLink').value;
            const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}?action=push&link=${encodeURIComponent(link)}`);
            const text = await response.text();
            alert(text);
        }

        async function deleteSong() {
            const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}?action=pop`);
            const text = await response.text();
            alert(text);
        }

        async function displayPlaylist() {
            const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}?action=display`);
            const text = await response.text();
            document.getElementById('playlist').innerText = text;
        }

        async function openTopSong() {
            const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}?action=open_top`);
            const text = await response.text();
            alert(text);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
`

and the code of cgi file is :
`// music-player/cgi-bin/music_player.cgi

#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class SongStack {
private:
    stack<T> s;
    string filename;

    void loadFromFile() {
        ifstream file(filename);
        if (file.is_open()) {
            T item;
            stack<T> tempStack;
            while (getline(file, item)) {
                tempStack.push(item);
            }
            while (!tempStack.empty()) {
                s.push(tempStack.top());
                tempStack.pop();
            }
            file.close();
        }
    }

    void saveToFile() {
        ofstream file(filename, ios::trunc);
        stack<T> tempStack = s;
        stack<T> reverseStack;
        while (!tempStack.empty()) {
            reverseStack.push(tempStack.top());
            tempStack.pop();
        }
        while (!reverseStack.empty()) {
            file << reverseStack.top() << endl;
            reverseStack.pop();
        }
        file.close();
    }

public:
    SongStack(const string& file) : filename(file) {
        loadFromFile();
    }

    void push(const T& item) {
        if (s.size() >= 5) {
            cout << "Stack Overflow...\n";
        } else {
            s.push(item);
            saveToFile();
            cout << "Song added successfully.\n";
        }
    }

    void pop() {
        if (s.empty()) {
            cout << "Stack is Empty ... \n";
        } else {
            T item = s.top();
            s.pop();
            saveToFile();
            cout << item << " is deleted successfully... \n";
        }
    }

    void display() {
        if (s.empty()) {
            cout << "Oops! Your playlist is Empty... \n";
        } else {
            stack<T> temp = s;
            while (!temp.empty()) {
                cout << temp.top() << " |<-- ";
                temp.pop();
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    void openTop() {
        if (s.empty()) {
            cout << "Oops! Your playlist is Empty... \n";
        } else {
            string link = s.top();
            cout << "Opening link: " << link << endl;
            // Platform-specific commands to open the link
            #ifdef _WIN32
                ShellExecute(0, 0, link.c_str(), 0, 0, SW_SHOW);
            #else
                string command = "xdg-open " + link;
                system(command.c_str());
            #endif
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";

    string query_string = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
    string action, link;

    if (!query_string.empty()) {
        size_t pos = query_string.find("action=");
        if (pos != string::npos) {
            size_t end = query_string.find('&', pos);
            action = query_string.substr(pos + 7, end - (pos + 7));
        }

        pos = query_string.find("link=");
        if (pos != string::npos) {
            link = query_string.substr(pos + 5);
        }
    }

    static SongStack<string> stack("/tmp/songstack.txt");

    if (action == "push" && !link.empty()) {
        stack.push(link);
    } else if (action == "pop") {
        stack.pop();
    } else if (action == "display") {
        stack.display();
    } else if (action == "open_top") {
        stack.openTop();
    } else {
        cout << "Invalid action or missing parameters.";
    }

    return 0;
}


and code for server.py is :
# music-player/server.py

import http.server
import socketserver
import os

PORT = 8000

class Handler(http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler):
    cgi_directories = ['/cgi-bin']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.chdir('html')
    with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
        print(f"Serving at port {PORT}")
        httpd.serve_forever()`


The error is :
enter image description here
i tried to make the cgi script executable by using chmod also and nothing is happening !!
Please HELP!!

chmod +x html/cgi-bin/music_player.cgi this also does not solve? Ensure you visit the correct URL (e.g., http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/music_player.cgi?action=display) to test the CGI script directly.
